# Craft Commerce payments not going through - status "redirect"

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, stripe, payment

I'm running a site taking orders via Craft Commerce. Most of the orders are fine, but a small percentage are failing, and going into the "Attempted Payments" section of the orders area.

If i go into the order, then look at the transactions tab, the order status is given as "Redirect". However, I can't find any information about what this means, or what might be causing the payment to fail. Can anyone help?

I am using Craft 3, and Stripe as the payment gateway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My money is on 3D Secure, a security protocol that requires card authentication before the card can be charged.
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure

So those "Redirect" orders are probably customers that were redirected to the authentication page but did not complete it.

Code seems to support this hypothesis:

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe/blob/b881fdde3a8d7253ae24c77ffd6feded0a91f4aa/src/gateways/Gateway.php#L535-L548

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe/blob/b881fdde3a8d7253ae24c77ffd6feded0a91f4aa/src/gateways/Gateway.php#L374-L382

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe/blob/b881fdde3a8d7253ae24c77ffd6feded0a91f4aa/src/responses/ChargeResponse.php#L89-L95

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/dd4822f2536aa6818acc0134a4a2e4b1b7d5dfef/src/services/Payments.php#L682-L683

Comment: Thanks, yes that does seem to be the reason for the error. Unfortunately, I've had a customer try multiple payments where they insist they are entering all of their info correctly and this is still failing.
Looks like some more testing for me!